# Why props is empty when passed to another page - React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to find a way to pass an id from the `Card.js` (nested in the `Home.js`). The idea is that when a user clicks on a card the **id attribute is obtained** and **passed to the `RecipeDetails.js` page as a variable** and the recipe details will show up on this page. I successfully passed the id up to `App.js` but when it is passed to the `RecipeDetails.js`,  the **props.id is always empty**. I did my research and **saw people using useHistory** but not sure how to implement it in my case. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

This is my app structure:
`App.js` 
----`Home.js` 
       ----`StaffPicks.js` 
            ----`<Card id={item.id}/>`  
----`RecipeDetails.js`

In details, the App.js I have 2 pages like below:

```js
function App(){
const [id, setId] = useState("");
useEffect(() => {}, [id]);
  return(
    <Switch>
      <Route
          path="/"
          exact
          component={() => (<Home/>)}
       />
       <Route
          path="/RecipeDetails"
          exact
          component={() => <RecipeDetails id={id}/>}
       />
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

`Card.js` Component:

```js
const MiniDishCard = (props) => {
  const [cardId, setCardId] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log(cardId);
    props.setId(cardId);
  }, [cardId]);

  return (
    <Gallery>
      {props.data.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <Card
            key={index}
            id={item.id}
            onClick={(e) => {
              setCardId(e.currentTarget.id);
            }}
          >
            <Link className="link" to="/RecipeDetails" target="_blank">
              <ImageWrapper>
                <img src={item.image} alt="Recipe Picture" />
              </ImageWrapper>
              <TextWrapper>
                <h3>{item.title}</h3>
                <IngredientsWrapper>
                  {item.missedIngredients.map((ingredient, index) => {
                    return <p key={index}>{ingredient.name}</p>;
                  })}
                  {item.usedIngredients.map((ingredient, index) => {
                    return (
                      <b key={index}>
                        <p>{ingredient.name}</p>
                      </b>
                    );
                  })}
                </IngredientsWrapper>
              </TextWrapper>
            </Link>
          </Card>
        );
      })}
    </Gallery>
  );
};

export default MiniDishCard;
```

`RecipeDetails.js` component:

```js
const DetailedRecipe = (props) => {
  const id = props.id;
  //console.log(id) always returns empty objects
  console.log(id)
  const info = {
    apiURL: `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/{id}/information`,
    apiKey: "***",
    apiURL2: `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/${id}/analyzedInstructions`,
  };
  
  const {
    data: recipe,
    error: recipeError,
    isLoading: recipeIsLoading,
  } = useFetch(`${info.apiURL}?apiKey=${info.apiKey}`);

  

  

  return ();
};
```

Comment: does the console.log in your useEffect in the Card.js component work?

Comment: Yes, it works, and I successfully passed the id all the way up to App,js but not to the RecipeDetails.js

Comment: Can you post your RecipeDetails.js?

Answer (score 0):

How about some context? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

```
export const AppContext = React.createContext(null)

function App() {
const [id, setId] = useState("");

return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ id, setId }}>
        <Switch>
            <Route
                path="/"
                exact
                component={() => (<Home/>)}
            />
            <Route
                path="/RecipeDetails"
                exact
                component={() => <RecipeDetails />}
            />
        </Switch>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

And in `RecipeDetails.js` and `Card.js`:

```
import { useContext } from 'react'
import { AppContext } from './App'

// Use inside components
const { id, setId } = useContext(AppContext)
```

Comment: It showed 2 errors: 
index.js:1 ./src/pages/RecipeDetails.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './App' in 'C:\Users\simon\Desktop\Coding\react projects\recipe-searching-website\src\pages'

AND 

index.js:1 src\pages\RecipeDetails.js
  Line 210:25:  'useContext' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: you need to import useContext. And maybe you should consider to cover the basics first, before you try the "advanced" stuff.

Comment: Edit: Added `import useContext` for clarity.
@Simon, you might need to import from `'../../../App'` in `Card.js`and `'../App'` in `RecipeDetails.js`

Comment: I successfully passed the id from `Card.js`  to the `App.js` component (using props) and just need to pass it the `RecipeDetails.js`. Do I still need to do that? I got the errors fixed btw

Comment: The id is already available in the `App.js` to be used but it's empty when passed to the `RecipeDetails.js`